# Pointing domain to CNAME

Tags: amazon-web-services, openshift

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I have pointed domains to git before which is a similar process.  Maybe a second pair of eyes will help.

I am routing the domain using amazon route 53 from namecheap.  I checked and the domain is pointing to the correct amazon aws servers. I created the cname on amazon like this:
www.parttimelandlord.net.
CNAME
http://ptl3-cmills83.rhcloud.com

Any help is appreciated.  I know for git I also needed an A record but it doesn't appear that is necessary for openshift bc the IP's change occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the "host" command on your domain name (that i copied and pasted from above) I get this:

```
cdaley-redhat:~ cdaley$ host www.parttimelandlord.net
Host www.parttimelandlord.net not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Looks like you either typed it incorrectly or????

Comment: yeah I even double checked the dns on the url and it is pointing to the aws urls, so I guess I'm trying to figure out the or???

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this is to switch to Heroku or another hosting provider.  It took <5 min to get the app/domain running on Heroku using the same process I was attempting with Openshift.